# Catch SOAP errors when using CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've trying to find a way of catching SOAP exceptions in a CodeIgniter model, I searched for hours and all I found was more people trying to get an answer without success.

How can I catch exceptions when creating a new instance of SoapClient?
I tried the following way but codeIgniter still gives me "A PHP Error was encountered" page, which in this project is fine in most of cases.

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->WAPI_service_url = 'http://api.lan/WAPITranslator/WAPITranslator.asmx?wsdl';

        try{
            $this->connection = new SoapClient($this->WAPI_service_url, array('trace' => 1, "exception" => 0));
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Following the [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php), i would do it like this:

```
class User_model extends CI_Model
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->WAPI_service_url = 'http://api.lan/WAPITranslator/WAPITranslator.asmx?wsdl';

        try {
            $this->connection = new SoapClient($this->WAPI_service_url, array('trace' => 1, "exceptions" => true));
        } catch (Exception $e){
            $e->getMessage(); // get the error message and save it somewhere
            $e->getCode(); // gets the error code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, codeigniter still gives the the same error if there's an issue with the connection. In my case I'm forcing the server receiving the SOAP request to be down.

Comment: Replace the `SoapFault` with `Exception` and you should be OK, i've tested it now.

Comment: That's wierd, are you using namespaces in the mentioned file? If so, you have to use `\Exception` instead of `Exception` in the catching block.

Comment: No, I'm not doing any thing special, using a codeigniter just downloaded...